# Functional application of a Collection<BiConsumer<A,B>> in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have this:

```
class Converter<A,B> {
  Collection<BiConsumer<A,B>> fieldconverters=...
  Class<B> targetclazz; // Set through constructor
  ...
  public B convert(A source) {
  B target=targetclazz.newInstance();
    for (BiConsumer<A,B> converter:fieldconverters)
      converter.accept(source,target);
    return target;
  }
}
```

Think of A and B being beans so that a `fieldconverter` looks like

```
(source,target)->target.setWhatever(someFunction(source.getWhatever()));
```

My question: Is it possible to write `convert` in a functional way, so that it starts like

```
public B convert(A source) {
  B target=targetclazz.newInstance();
  fieldconverters.stream().<this-and-that-with-source-and-target>;
  return target;
}
```

Is this possible? Is it sensible? I thought about this now for some time and have not found a solution (despite the good old for-loop...). Am I missing something or is my idea of a functional approach in this constellation simply wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
fieldconverters.forEach(converter -> converter.accept(source, target));
```

As an aside, instead of having `Class<B>` as a field and creating target via reflection, consider having a `Supplier<B>` as a field.  Then your `convert` method can be written as

```
public B convert(A source) {
    B target = targetSupplier.get();    
    fieldconverters.forEach(converter -> converter.accept(source, target));
    return target;
}
```

You can use a lambda expression to create `Supplier<B>` when you call the constructor.

Comment: Should be mentioned that now `targetSupplier` has to be initialized with `SomeClass::new` when previously `targetclazz` was with `SomeClass.class`.

Comment: Thanks, that, of course, did it. I must admit that I am still in the process of becoming familiar with this functional style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use a Supplier for the instantation of `target`. However, the code performs a huge amount of reflection under the hood so the `Class` is available nevertheless and I can use it without problems.

Comment: @Dirk Hillbrecht: you should use a `Supplier`, even when the `Class` is available, as a `Supplier` created via `Type::new` guarantees at compile-time that an accessible no-arg constructor exists, that it doesn’t throw surprising checked exceptions and that the generic type is correct, if the class to instantiate is generic. In contrast, `Class.newInstance()` will compile and errors are spot at runtime only, some of them may stay unrecognized in some executions (like when testing) and fail in others (at the customer)…

Comment: @Holger: You are absolutely right and the advantage of compile time error vs. runtime error is indeed really important. In my very special case, however, I am working on JAXB-generated classes and using reflection all over. Therefore, this very special implementation will stay with `newInstance()`. Note that generification can help even in this case as something like `public <A> void register(Class<A> x,Converter<A> y)` can guarantee at compile time that class and converter match and a `(Converter<A>)y` will not run in a `ClassCastException`. New idioms help old structures...